# How do I set up an SFML .NET dll reference in Visual Studio Code

Tags: c#, sfml, .net, dll, visual-studio-code

How do I set up SFML .NET library dll files as references in Visual studio code using dotnet core SDK? I want to ditch visual studio as it's large and clunky and am wondering how to add "third party" .dll's as references like I can in visual studio by right clicking the references tab in the project explorer and selecting the dll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added these references manually to .csproj file as item group. e.g. https://github.com/kubagdynia/Spacetris/blob/master/Spacetris/Spacetris.csproj